# equation involving exponential in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to figure out the colutions in $\mathbb{C}$ of the equation $e^{iz^2}=1$. Here is what i get :

Set $z=a+ib$. Computing i get $e^{-2ab+i(a^2-b^2)}=e^{-2ab}e^{i(a^2-b^2)}=1$

thus $a$ or $b$ is $0$ and $a^2\equiv b^2 \pmod{2\pi}$. This means, say, $a=0$ and $b=\pm\sqrt{2k\pi}$ for some integer $k$. The solutions are thus of the form $z=\pm i\sqrt{2k\pi}$ for some integer $k$ (or $z=\pm\sqrt{2k\pi}$, assuming $b=0$).

Is it correct? is there a better way to put up those solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your equation to:

$$e^{iz^2} = 1 = e^{2k\pi i} \qquad k \in \Bbb Z$$

hence

$$z^2 = 2k\pi$$

must hold. Taking the root delivers

$$z = \pm \sqrt{2k\pi} \qquad k \geq 0$$
$$z = \pm i \sqrt{2|k|\pi} \qquad k < 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $e^{iz^2}=\cos z^2+i\sin z^2=\cos 0+i\sin 0$.

Now, equating the real and imaginary terms, do the general solutions. It will be easier.

This appears, $$\cos z^2=\cos 0\\\implies z^2=\pm 2k\pi$$.

Hence, your solution.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{iz^2}=1\implies z^2=2\pi k\implies z=\pm\sqrt{2\pi k}$

Comment: i can't see how this can be generalized to, say, $e^{z^2}=1$. Could you solve it the same way?

Comment: Look at your question. It says $e^{iz^2}$. But yes, you get $z^2 = 2\pi ki$ and solve that.